# How to return 404 page for a server-side rendered dynamic route after client-side page transition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working on a next.js project with Contentful as Content Management System.
I want to return the 404 page for a server-side rendered dynamic route after a client-side page transition.

When I request the page directly (by entering the url or refresh the page) everything's working fine and the 404 page gets returned.
But when the user is already on the site and navigates through a "next/link" Link (client-side page transition) to a server-side rendered page, getServerSideProps only returns the JSON that contains the result. Which is ok as documented here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-on-server-side.
This results in a completely empty website and the following console error:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (page.json, line 0)

Here's my getServerSideProps of the page I want navigate to:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }: Params) => {
  const { slug } = params;
  try {
    const entry: Entry<any> = await (
      await ContentfulService.getInstance().getEntryBySlugAndType(slug, 'page', 4)
    ).items[0];
    const page: IPageFields = entry.fields;
    return {
      props: { page }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any opportunity to return the 404 page also for a client-side page transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just could fix my problem by adding a simple getStaticProps to my 404 page.

Like this:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {}
  };
};
```